# How to retrive the following json data in php

Tags: php, json, decoding

i've the following json data with the following structure

```
{

    "page": 0,
    "items": 43,
    "total": 43,
    "incentiveItems": {
        "incentiveItem": [
            {
                "@id": "1111",
                "name": "...",
                "program": {
                    "@id": "6765",
                    "$": "NAME"
                },
                "admedia": {
                    "admediumItem": {
                        ...
```

and more, to parse the data in php i do a simple foreach...

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonData);
echo $obj->items;
echo '<table><tr><td>Nome</td><td>Descrizione</td><td>Codice</td></tr>';
foreach($obj->incentiveItems->incentiveItem as $programma  ) {
```

so, the problem is that i can't call the "$" :" NAME" value, coz if i use (for ex)

```
$programma->program->$
$programma->program['$']
$obj->incentiveItems->incentiveItem->program->$ or ['$']
```

it crash

and the same is for the @id field.

can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tyr decoding json as associative array:

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonData, true);
echo $obj['items'];
echo '<table><tr><td>Nome</td><td>Descrizione</td><td>Codice</td></tr>';
foreach($obj['incentiveItems']['incentiveItem'] as $programma  ) {
  echo $programma['@id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use single quotes and curly brackets to access it

```
$obj->incentiveItems->incentiveItem->program->{'$'}

$obj->incentiveItems->incentiveItem->program->{'@id'}
```

Comment: @Pigi don't forget to upvote/accept any useful answers (mine or otherwise) :)